# gcc could not find header files on mac os catalina

Tags: gcc, anaconda, conda, static-libraries, macos-catalina

I am installing a package (called CLASS, widely used in cosmology) which cannot be compiled with Apple's gcc.

I tried installing gcc by homebrew (gcc-9) and anaconda separately. But both of them could not find the standard C-library files such as stdio.h, math.h etc. I saw this problem very common in mac. I found the standard C-library files at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/`. Focusing on anaconda gcc (version 4.8.5), I then copied the files to `/Users/satadru/anaconda2/include/`. Now simple C-codes, such as a 'hello world' code runs fine. But when I tried to install the CLASS package, I get error arising from the problematic library files: stdio.h, math.h!! I get same error when I try to install the package using homebrew gcc-9 (after copying the library files to its concerned directory). I know that many people could run the package on catalina without any issue.

Now I have the following questions:

1. Are all standard C-library header files same? In other words, be it anaconda gcc 4.8.5, or gcc-9, the header files are same? Do the header files vary on different os, say linux or mac os?
2. Does anaconda gcc look for the header files at `/Users/satadru/anaconda2/include/`?
3. Before copying all the header files to `/Users/satadru/anaconda2/include/`, the directory had a few present there. 
   Why does not anaconda gcc installation place all of its own header files in this directory at the time of installation? Is it same when we do it on linux os?
4. How to solve my problem? I contacted the owner of the package and he says he himself runs the code on mac os catalina, but never faced this issue.

More information:

```
xcode-select --install
```

gives

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

`which gcc` gives `/Users/satadru/anaconda2/bin/gcc`

`gcc -v` gives

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Users/satadru/anaconda2/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-gxx-include-dir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/gcc/include/c++ --bindir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/bin --datarootdir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/share --libdir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/lib --with-gmp=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-mpfr=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-mpc=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-isl=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-cloog=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-boot-ldflags='-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-L/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/lib -Wl,-L/usr/lib' --with-stage1-ldflags='-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-L/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/lib -Wl,-L/usr/lib' --enable-checking=release --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 (GCC)
```

Comment: _I am installing package which cannot be compiled with Apple’s gcc_ Which package? Are you really using Anaconda 2?

Comment: The package is CLASS in cosmology. I am using anaconda 2 because I have many difficult packages installed on it. However, I found a way of copying the library header files to anaconda include directory. After doing this, simple c codes (say a hello world code) is running fine. But the package installation still gives error arising from this copied library files. I will change this question.

Comment: Can you share a link to the package?

Comment: Fortunately I'm also on macOS Catalina, so I'm going to try the installation myself.

Comment: https://lesgourg.github.io/class_public/class.html

Download the package, untar it. Then use `make clean` and then `make class` or just `make`. The steps are fairly easy and there is no problem what so ever in linux.

Thank you

Comment: I have made a tiny bit of progress, I think. I changed the makefile to include the C headers, which solves the “can’t find stdio.h” issue. The file contains a section where you can choose to activate or deactivate something called hyrec (?), in both cases I get different errors, on of which involves yet another header (limits.h). That’s all I have for now.